# online reservations import calendar application

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I have an online booking system for my small business.
I would like to have the reservations of these bookings to be sent to my desktop calendar and added automatically. 
First question: is this possible?

At the moment I am using outlook 2010 on an apple. There you have the possibility of adding colors to appointments.
Second question: is it possible to add these colors automatically to the file that is being sent from the website?

Third question: I want to get rid of Parallels on my apple. Are there professional calendar applications that have the same possibilities as outlook 2010?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ideally your online booking system would issue an ics feed (possibly with an 'obscured/private' url) - ask them if they do (some do).  Then you could subscribe to that ics feed in outlook and have it visible as a separate calendar to your main personal but seeing both at the same time.   If the booking system feed has categories for the events these would be in the ics feed and some calendar applications might use these when displaying events.

I don't know anything about parallels and apple.  It would be better to split different questions into separate posts.